# Can't pass the function as parameter from router file

Tags: node.js, jwt

```
router.route('/:id',verifyAuthrisation).put(updateUser)
```

in routes folder

This code in the controller

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const accessToken = jwt.sign({
    id:Users._id,
    isAdmin:Users.isAdmin
},process.env.JWTSEC,
{expiresIn:"3d"}
)

const updateUser=async(req,res)=>{
    if(req.body.password){
        req.body.password=md5(req.body.password)
    }
const updatedUser=await Users.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{
    $set:req.body
},{new:true})
res.json(updatedUser)
}
///////////////////////////////////midleware folder↓
const jwt=require("jsonwebtoken")
const verifyToken=(req,res,next)=>{
    const authHeader=req.headers.token
    if(authHeader){
        const token=authHeader.split(" ")[1]
        jwt.verify(token,process.env.JWTSEC,(err,user)=>{
            if(err) {res.json("token is not valid")};

            req.user=user;
            next();
console.log(req.user.id);
        });
    }else{
        return res.json("you are not authenticated")
    }
};

const verifyAuthrisation=(req,res,next)=>{
    verifyToken(req,res,()=>{
       
        if(req.user.id === (req.params.id || req.user.isAdmin)){
            next();
        }else{
         
            res.json("you are not alowed")
        }
    });
};

module.exports={
    verifyToken,
    verifyAuthrisation
}
```

problem that  when i pass the token the if condition dont work and the else mesage came out "you are not alowed" and i think that happens becouse it cant define req.user.id as it said in console.log and when i try to conole.log req.user it sends { iat: 1640554054, exp: 1640813254 } so where is the id property

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `router.route('/:id',verifyAuthrisation).put(updateUser)`

Try `router.route('/:id').put(verifyAuthrisation, updateUser)`

According to [the docs of Express](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router), the function `router.route` accepts only one argument, which is the route template. The middlewares are the arguments for method function

Comment: there still a problem that even when i pass the token the if condition dont work and the else mesage came out "you are not alowed" and i think that happens becouse it cant define req.user.id as it said in console.log and when i try to conole.log req.user it sends { iat: 1640554054, exp: 1640813254 } so where is the id property

Comment: there still a problem that even when i pass the token the if condition dont work and the else mesage came out "you are not alowed" and i think that happens becouse it cant define req.user.id as it said in console.log and when i try to conole.log req.user it sends { iat: 1640554054, exp: 1640813254 } so where is the id property @Ron B.